# Salvar campo input no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Como armazenar as ultimas 100 pesquisas feitas a um site (PHP/MYSQL) dividas por países (ex: armazenar as ultimas 100 pesquisas por livros da Macedônia). A pesquisa é um campo simples simples:

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" />
```

Qual a melhor forma de "coleta" desta informação que não comprometa a performance (eu julgo que a cada nova pesquisa ter de inserir no banco seja demasiadamente oneroso), e a melhor forma de estruturar esta informação em tabelas no banco? e como criar uma limitação a 100 pesquisas por país e trabalhar de forma semelhante a uma fila (mantendo sempre atualizada as 100 pesquisas)? Esta lista deve ser acessível a todos os usuários e atualizada em tempo real como fazer a nível de aplicação também.

Tabela País:

```
CREATE TABLE pais(
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
codigo CHAR(2) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
nome VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

Obs: este código é o código ISO do país.

Comment: Queres armazenar  `id_pais => palavra_pesquisada`?

Comment: sim seria tipo uma tabela onde uma coluna fosse o id país e na outra a palavra pesquisada, o problema que como são muitas pesquisas eu gostaria de uma forma mais eficiente de fazer a inserção no banco

Comment: Podes sempre guardar num log e ao fim do dia, numa hora morta fazer a inserção no banco. Ou tem de ser atualizado na hora?

Comment: @JorgeB. dever ser atualizado em tempo real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor maneira eu não se é, mas tenho algumas idéias

**SOLUÇÃO 1**

1. Criar uma *TRIGGER* no *AFTER INSERT* da sua tabela, essa trigger faz uma chamada para uma *FUNCTION*.
2. Criar a *FUNCTION* de forma recursiva fazendo as seguintes operações:

---

- Fazer uma consulta que retorne quantos registros a tabela possui, leia sobre *COUNT()*
- Fazer uma condição nessa consulta se for maior que 100, então remove o primeiro registro, leia sobre *MIN()*
- Fazer a condição de parada, para sair da recursividade quando o resultado da consulta for menor ou igual a 100

---

### Solução 2

fazer o delete dos registros antigos diretamente (sem recursividade)

```
DELETE FROM pais WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM  (SELECT id FROM pais ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100) alias);
```

> solução 2 - referência: http://www.olamundo.blog.br/blog/?p=63

Comment: ,@SneepS NinjA, como estes dados terão de ser atualizados em tempo real isso não pode ser oneroso? alem desta abordagem há como fazer isto a nível de aplicação tipo fila em PHP? (a proposito muito boa sua solução)